# Minecraft: After tunneling via ssh I get the following

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, linux

So I have a similar problem to this thread:
[Using SOCKS with Minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/257600/using-socks-with-minecraft)

Addison Crump's "another method" essentially helped me coming to the point where I am now.

I did the following:

I replaced my current JVM with this: `-DsocksProxyHost=127.0.0.1 -DsocksProxyPort=3128 -DproxySet=true -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="localhost|127.0.0.1"`

start MC with that profile and then put: `ssh (ssh file that automatically connects via a tunnel on port 80 with the username pi and logs me in on my Linux RaspberryPi) -L 25565:minecraftserverexample.net:25565`

Now I add the server localhost:25565

And get the server... but when I try to join, I get the response: "Failed to login: Authentication servers are currently under maintenance" ... or sth like that.

Please help, I don´t know what's the problem.

Comment: Tunnel via a pickaxe instead ;-)

Comment: "or something like that" Can you please actually copy error messages from logs or screenshot them from the game?

Comment: Wow, a properly asked question by a new user, even with correct tags! I hope that you get an answer, I don't usually see many people here answering highly technical questions.

Comment: Look at the comment under 'another method'. It seems you set up the connection to the remote server just fine but you don't have connection to Mojang's auth servers.

Comment: So the question is how to get connection to the authentication servers.